# Rudin's RCA, Theorem $4.15$

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, orthonormal

There is   the  definition which we need for $4.15$
[image]

There is the theorem :
[image]

There is $4.15$:

We want to drop the finiteness condition that appears in Theorem $4.14$ without even restricting ourselves to sets that are necessarily countable. For this reason it seems advisable to clarify the meaning of the symbol $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha)$ when $\alpha$ ranges over an arbitrary set $A$.

Assume $0$ $\leq$ $\varphi(\alpha)$ $\in$ $\infty$ for each $\alpha$ $\in$ $A$.

Then $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha)$

denotes the supremum of the set of all finite sums $\varphi(\alpha_1)$ $+$ ... $+$ $\varphi(\alpha_n)$, where
$\alpha_1$,...$\alpha_n$ are distinct members of $A$.

A moment's consideration will show that the sum $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha)$ is thus precisely the Lebesgue integral of $\varphi$ relative to the counting measure $\mu$ on $A$.

I don't understand why is the sum $\sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha)$ the Lebesgue integral of $\varphi$ relative to the counting measure $\mu$ on $A$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{\alpha\in A}\phi(\alpha)u_\alpha$ is defined in terms of  limit of a net:  the set of all finite subsets $J$ of $A$ with the direction given by inclusion, that is $J\leq I$ iff $J\subset I$. That is because sums are in principle defined for finite number of terms. Convergence of nets can be found in Kelly's, General Topology for example. In the setting of the OP, $\sum_{\alpha}\phi(\alpha)$ if  it exists, is $s\in H$ such that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite set $J_\varepsilon$ such that $|s-\sum_{\alpha\in I}\phi(\alpha)u_\alpha|<\varepsilon$ whenever $J\subset I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\int \varphi \ d\mu = \sup \int s \ d\mu$, where the supremum is taken over all positive simple functions $s \leq \varphi$. That's how we define integrals over positive functions.

Since $\mu$ is the counting measure, any function $A \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is measurable. The positive *simple* functions are precisely the functions $A \to \mathbb R$ that take finitely many distinct values. A positive simple function therefore takes the form
$$ s = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mathbf 1_{E_i},$$
where the $E_i$'s are disjoint subsets of $A$ and the $c_i$'s are strictly positive real numbers.

The integral of this simple function is
$$ \int s  \ d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \ \mu(E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \ |E_i|,$$
where $|E_i|$ is the cardinality of $E_i$. (The fact that $\mu(E_i) = |E_i|$ follows from the fact that $\mu$ is the counting measure.)

Now let's return to the evaluation of $\int \varphi \ d\mu$.

There are two cases.

**Case 1:** there exists some positive simple function $s = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mathbf 1_{E_i} $ bounded by $\varphi$ where at least one of the $E_i$'s is an infinite set. In this situation, $\int s \ d\mu = \infty$, and therefore $\int \varphi \ d\mu = \infty$.

Without loss of generality, let's say that $E_1$ is infinite. Let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \dots$ be a sequence of distinct elements of $E_1$. Then for any $K \in \mathbb N$, we have
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^K \varphi(\alpha_k) \geq K \times c_1 $$
so
$$ \sup_{k \in \mathbb N} \sum_{k = 1}^K \varphi(\alpha_k) = \infty.$$

Thus $$ \sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha) = \infty = \int \varphi \ d\mu$$ in this case.

**Case 2:** For all positive simple functions $s = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mathbf 1_{E_i} $ bounded by $\varphi$, all of the $E_i$'s are finite sets.

In this case, each positive simple function bounded by $\varphi$ can be written as $\sum_{j = 1}^J c_j \mathbf 1_{\{\alpha_j\}}$, where each $\{\alpha_j\}$ is a *singleton* set, and where $0 < c_j \leq \varphi(\alpha_j)$. The sum over $j$ is finite, and the $\alpha_j$'s are distinct. (The $\alpha_j$'s in this sum are precisely the members of the $E_i$'s in the previous sum. The fact that all of the $E_i$'s are finite sets means that the sum over $j$ is finite.)

The integral of this simple function is $ \sum_{j=1}^J c_j $.

All positive simple functions $s \leq \varphi$ can be written in the form $s = \sum_{j = 1}^J c_j \mathbf 1_{\{\alpha_j\}}$ where each  $0 < c_j \leq \varphi(\alpha_j)$ and where the $\alpha_j$'s are distinct. Conversely, any function of the form $s = \sum_{j = 1}^J c_j \mathbf 1_{\{\alpha_j\}}$ where $0 < c_j \leq \varphi(\alpha_j)$ and the $\alpha_j$'s are distinct is a positive simple function $\leq \varphi$. Taking the supremum over the integrals of all such positive simple functions, we see that
$$ \int \varphi \ d\mu = \sum_{\alpha \in A} \varphi(\alpha)$$
in this case too.

Comment: I don't understand what does the fact that $\mu$ is counting measure give us ?

Comment: Firstly, the fact that $\mu$ is the counting measure tells you that any function on $A$ is measurable. Secondly, the fact that $\mu$ is the counting measure tells you that the measure of a singleton set $\{ \alpha_i \}$ is equal to 1. We use both these facts.

Comment: How does this fact tell us that any function on $A$ is measurable ? Also where did we use the fact that the measure of a singleton set is equal to $1$?

Comment: The  sigma algebra associated with the counting measure contains all subsets of $A$. In other words, all subsets of $A$ are considered to be measurable when you're using the counting measure. A function $f : A \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}((c, \infty))$ is measurable for any $c$. If all subsets of $A$ are measurable, then this condition clearly holds.

Comment: We used the fact that the measure of a singleton set is 1 when we evaluated the integral $\int \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mathbf 1_{\alpha_i} \ d\mu $. By definition, this integral equals $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \mu(\{ \alpha_i\})$. But each of the $\mu(\{\alpha_i\})$'s is one, since the measure of a singleton set is 1. Hence the integral of this simple function is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i $

Comment: Sorry, I realised I missed something important. I'll edit this...

Comment: So sorry for all the edits. I wasn't expecting this to be so fiddly! It seems like you can think faster than I can type. :)